# Could a CURL call has no '--request' param?

Tags: curl, httpclient

What is the difference between following two requests.

Second one has no '--request' param, what does it mean?
First call returns auth token, second one returns metadata of an object with certain id

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://****.azure-api.net/test/mosaic/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Length: 1024' \
--header 'grant_type: client_credentials' \
--header 'client_secret: ***' \
--header 'scope: bpm-portal' \
--header 'client_id: b82346bc-05f6-46ef-a1df-8fe0eaa420b8' \
--header 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: *****'
```

```
curl --location 'https://**.azure-api.net/test/mosaicId/SearchMosaicById?id=RLA217545' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Length: 1024' \
--header 'grant_type: client_credentials' \
--header 'client_secret: ****' \
--header 'scope: bpm-portal' \
--header 'client_id: b82346bc-05f6-46ef-a1df-8fe0eaa420b8' \
--header 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: *****' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer "*****' \
--header 'Accept: application/xml'
```

I test this in Postman.
First call goes ok, but second one fails 'HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.' Which type of request should be used??

Comment: It would help if you could explain which parts of the documentation of curl you don’t understand.

Comment: is it possible to run second request in Postman?

Answer (score -1):

Can't be no type

Syntax w/o this param means GET type